# Chrome won't load simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My JavaScript inside the `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function over1() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("1").src;
    document.getElementById("big").src = img1;
}

function out() {
    document.getElementById("big").src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/shop-icon.png";
}

function london() {
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var check = city.toLowerCase();
    var province = document.getElementById("province").value;

    if (check == "london" && province == "ON") {
        alert("Visit our company travel store at Masonville Mall!");
    }
}

function  checkinput()  {
    var email = document.contest.email.value;
    var emailcheck = email.search("@");

    if (!document.contest.name.value)  {
        alert("Enter a name!")

    } else {

        alert("Thank You " + document.contest.name.value + " " + document.contest.lastname.value + " For Entering The Contest!")
        window.open(calculator.html,'_blank');
    }
}
</script>
```

I have the simple JavaScript inside the HTML file, but Chrome won't read it. In Inspector View, it throws ReferenceErrors for all my functions. Please help.

Comment: What errors are you getting, where is this `<script>` at in your page, shoe your relevant html please.

Comment: Just a note: `type` is optional in html5

Comment: The script is at the top after title tages in the head section of the website. I did my website in [codepen](http://codepen.io/romankoval10/pen/RRWGqQ), but it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: @RomanK - Listen, you need to put forth the effort to ask a proper question if you want timely, informative responses. Please provide additional code (HTML, etc) to your question so people can help you. As your code (looks) stands right now, I have no reason to believe it won't parse and returns *reference* errors. There is more to this story that you're choosing to omit.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of scripts in the head. Try putting it just before closing the`body`. But this is *not* the cause of your errors.

Comment: @Marcus the code is [HERE](http://codepen.io/romankoval10/pen/RRWGqQ) All I Did Was Copy It To A HTML File And Ran It With Chrome. I Put My JavaScript Inside The Head Section Of The Webpage.

Comment: Your codepen works fine. Not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say that, those are all functions, nothing is invoked from these functions. call the functions and see if they are invoked correctly or not

```
      checkinput();
      over1();
      /* the rest of them */
```

Comment: I put your code in an html page and I am not getting any error, rather I am able to run the functions correctly

Comment: Ok, cleaned up your code and it is working now, you can find it in https://jsfiddle.net/s9gojfvf/ When using JavaScript, I highly recommend separating your code and using some sort of lint, it'd keep the code in good hygiene.